# Ignore empty strings in mapconcat?

Tags: lisp, elisp

I'm trying to insert a comma-separated string generated from a few values input by the user.  If a particular value is empty, I don't want to insert that value.  My problem is that `mapconcat` is still inserting the separator when the function returns `nil`.  I have also tried doing this with the `unless` control in the list instead of the function with the same result.

```
(insert (mapconcat 
         (function (lambda (x) (unless (string-equal x "") x))))
         (list input-a input-b input-c)
         ", "))
```

If the values from the user are `"foo"`, `""`,and `"bar"`, the output will be `"foo, , bar"`; I would like it to be `"foo, bar"`.  How can I prevent the separator from being inserted when the input value is empty?

Comment: Do you also want to ignore strings containing only whitespace?  E.g., `" "`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your list contains `nil` values, and `mapconcat` will still process those, so you need to *remove* the unwanted items from the list first.

Exactly how you do that will depend upon whether you need to retain the list in its original form as well. Here's an option which *doesn't* modify the original list:

```el
(setq my-list (list "foo" "" "bar"))
(mapconcat 'identity
           (remove "" my-list)
           ", ")
```

If you didn't need the original, you could use `delete` instead of `remove`; but make sure you read the help for `delete` if you do.